# how to use variable with shell commands in python

Tags: python, bash, shell, variables

this is my piece of code

```
        run_command("clear")
        print("Initializing Scraper .........")
        time.sleep(2)
        username = input("Enter your instagram Username : ")
        password = input("Enter your instagram Password : ")
        targeted_account = input("Username of account which needs to be scraped : ")
        print("Running Scraper...")
        time.sleep(2)
        command = "instagram-scraper {victim} -u {username} -p {password}"
        run_command("command")
```

i want python to run the command with those variables and i cant figure out how to do that.

Comment: you want to execute terminal commands with python?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command

Answer (score 0):

Use `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['instagram-scraper', victim, '-u', username, '-p', password])
```